# "Cannot execute binary file " error on a server -> why ? Linux core?

Tags: binary, scilab

I'm trying to run Scilab on a server and when calling the Scilab-5.5.1/bin/scilab script I get :

> scilab-5.5.1-32bits/bin/scilab: line 925: scilab-5.5.1-32bits/bin/scilab-bin: cannot execute binary file

I tried to compare *file /bin/bash* with *file scilab-5.5.1-32bits/bin/scilab-bin* I get :

> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

for bash and for Scilab :

> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

Question : Is the *dynamically linked/statically linked* changing anything ? same question for the missing "*for GNU/Linux 2.6.18*" ?

The *uname -a* command gives me :

> Linux webm339.xxl.ha.ovh.net 3.10.23-grsec-hosting-build7-web #134 SMP Wed Aug 27 12:51:49 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

So is this Linux core able to run Scilab binary's ? If not Is there a way to compile Scilab sources by myself for this core ?

I precise that all files are chmod 755.

Answer (score 0):

So I answer (it can be usefull for someone who wants scilab on a server) :

by installing libc6-dev-i386 on my 64 bit pc, I compiled (gcc -m32) an hello world which is running ...

Compiling a minimal scilab ([doc here](http://wiki.scilab.org/Description%20of%20configure%20options)) might be a solution.

I'll back